# Time Period Analysis in SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I have a question regarding problems that require us to find time period of an oscillating setup that performs SHM. The question is as follows-

The pulley shown in figure below has a moment of inertia I about its axis and mass m. Find the time period of vertical oscillation of its center of mass. The spring has spring constant k and the string does not slip over the pulley.

[image: pulley spring image]

This question is from a reputed book from India, Concepts of Physics by HC Verma.
While solving this question the author has considered the energy of the system at a certain extention $x$ and differentiated it with respect to time and stated that as the mechanical energy remains constant, it's change with time must be 0, and then proceeded to obtain the time period as follows -

At equilibrium position, Let tension in string be T, and extension in spring is $x_0$, for rotational equilibrium $T = kx_0$ and for translational equilibrium $ 2kx_0 = mg$ or $x_0=\frac{mg}{2k}$

Now considering the pulley to be displaced downwards by a small distance $x$, the spring stretches by $2x$ and the total mechanical energy of the system, considering the equilibrium position to be the reference for potential energy can be given as,
$$
U = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 + \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - mgx + \frac{1}{2}k\bigg(\frac{mg}{2k}+2x\bigg)^2  
$$
where $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the rotating pendulum, and as the pendulum does not slip over the string, we can say $\omega = \frac{v}{r^2}$ substituting this gives

$$
U = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{I}{r^2}+m\bigg)v^2 + \frac{m^2g^2}{8k^2} + 2kx^2  
$$

Next, as the system is conservative the total mechanical energy is conserved and $\frac{dU}{dt} = 0$
Which gives,

$$
0 = \bigg(\frac{I}{r^2} + m\bigg)v\frac{dv}{dt} + 4kxv
$$

with some algebra, isolating $\frac{dv}{dt}$ on one side and using it with $a = -\omega^2x$ and solving for $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$ we get

$$
T = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{\bigg(\frac{I}{r^2} + m\bigg)}{4k}}
$$

I have no problem with this solution, however I am curious if this problem can be solved by analysing the forces on the pulley, getting an equation for the restoring force and using the fact that a restoring force is related to $\omega$ as $F = -m\omega^2x$
This is how I usually solve for time period, by analysing the restoring force.
If it is not possible, why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question about an alternative approach to this type of problem, and not a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: The short answer is that if you have conservation of mechanical energy, differentiating $E = \text{const.}$ with respect to time always yields $ma = F$.  In other words, if you tried to write down the forces from scratch, you'd end up with exactly the same equation.